# Insert into cmd with value from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to build SQL command.

I have 2 tables,
the first one has :

```
songname - string
genre - int
```

The second has :

```
genre - int
genrename - string
```

I want to build a command that will do insert:

```
INSERT INTO Songs (songname,genre) VALUES (blablabla,*)
```

and instead of the * I want to take the value from the second table where genrename is equal to 3 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Songs (songname,genre) 
SELECT 'blablabla', S.VALUE
FROM SECONDTABLE S
WHERE genrename = 3
```

Comment: and if for example i dont have 3 in the secondtable did i get 0 in S.VALUE ?

Comment: @MTA, If *secondtable* table doesn't have *3* in *genrename*, then no record will be inserted into *Songs* table.

Comment: And if there are many rows in secondtable with `genrename=3`, many rows will be inserted in `Songs`.